Connecting AWS Lambda in Go to RDS
I'm trying to set up a simple API using API Gateway, Lambda (in Go) and RDS. I've got the API Gateway and lambda function communicating properly, however I can't figure out how to access my database from inside the Go code. I'm using Terraform to create the infrastructure.
Here's my RDS setup (the hardcoded username and password are only for the sake of simplicity for this post):
resource "aws_db_instance" "bl-db" {
  allocated_storage       = 5 # gigabytes
  engine                  = "postgres"
  engine_version          = "16.4"
  identifier              = "main"
  instance_class          = "db.t3.micro"
  username                = "myname"
  password                = "mypassword"
  publicly_accessible     = false
}

Here's my lambda IAM role:
resource "aws_iam_role" "hello" {
  name               = "hello"
  assume_role_policy = <<POLICY
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
    "Principal": {
      "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
    },
    "Effect": "Allow"
  }
}
POLICY
}

And for my lambda code this is what I have currently, but I'm assuming I'm quite far off.
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "log"

    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/events"
    "github.com/aws/aws-lambda-go/lambda"
    "github.com/jmoiron/sqlx"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

// The input type and the output type are defined by the API Gateway.
func handleRequest(req events.APIGatewayProxyRequest) (events.APIGatewayProxyResponse, error) {
    db, err := sqlx.Connect("postgres", "user=postgres dbname=main sslmode=disable password=mypassword host=myhost")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
    }
  
    defer db.Close()

    // Test the connection to the database
    if err := db.Ping(); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        log.Println("Successfully Connected")
    }

    db.Queryx("some sql query")

    res := events.APIGatewayProxyResponse{
        StatusCode: http.StatusOK,
        Headers:    map[string]string{"Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8"},
        Body:       fmt.Sprintf("Hello!\n"),
    }
    return res, nil
}

func main() {
    lambda.Start(handleRequest)
}


Ok, and are there any errors in the logs? Is the Lambda function in a VPC? Does the RDS security group allow communication from Lambda? There are some details missing I think.

Yes, but I can't make much sense of it. I just get "{"errorMessage":"2024-08-22T11:00:53.558Z 8ad0ea6d-178d-44d4-85b9-0706748cc26f Task timed out after 1.00 seconds"}", but I doubt this operation should take any more than a second.

Sorry, I'm pretty new to AWS so I get all of the VPC/IAM/Subnet concepts mixed up, but I would not be surprised if I've done something wrong there. From what I understand, the database and lambda have t be in the same VPC? I'm not sure that I have set up an RDS security group, as the piece I attached is really the only RDS-related code.

Can you also share the terraform code for the Lambda function, if you used it that way?

The default Lambda function timeout is 3 seconds so it looks like you reduced it to 1 second. I wouldn't do that while trying to debug something like connectivity to a database. Also, generally, reducing that timeout value is not a very common occurrence. Was there a specific reason to reduce it?

Maybe you have omitted them for brevity, however, I see no aws_security_group_rule resource allowing ingress from your lambda function to an RDS instance.
